# Dictionary declaration in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have declared a dictionary

```
data=dict(key="sadasfd",secret="1213",to="23232112",text="sucess",from='nattu')
```

It is showing error in python, saying that keyword is used. Why does it is not taking `from`?

Whenever I encounter with `from` as a key in dictionary, I can't use it.

Comment: Works fine: http://repl.it/RkL

Comment: because from is a keyword...

Comment: hey who down voted see my question ...it wont work

Comment: @Nattu The code that you've posted actually works, there's a difference between `From` and `from`.

Comment: why inside dict it accepting keywords.. so v cant use Dict if v have key as From..

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary ur right .. please make it as answer...

Comment: @Nattu: Because Python *syntax* supports keyword arguments, why **not** have `dict()` accept keyword arguments? That functionality is handy sometimes, but is limited by only allowing valid *identifiers* as keys. That means no integers either, for example.

Comment: See my comments on the other answer for an explanation and examples of what `dict()` should be used for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`from` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) and cannot be used as a keyword argument to the `dict()` constructor.

Use a [`{...}` dictionary literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) instead:

```
data = {'key': "sadasfd", 'secret': "1213", 
        'to': "23232112", 'text': "sucess", 'from': 'nattu'}
```

or assign to the key afterwards:

```
data['from'] = 'nattu'
```

or avoid using reserved keywords altogether.

Python supports passing arbitrary keywords to a callable, and uses dictionaries to capture such arguments, so it is a logical extension that the `dict()` constructor accepts keyword arguments. But such arguments *are* limited to valid [Python identifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) *only*. If you want to use anything else (reserved keywords, strings starting with integers or containing spaces, integers, floats, tuples, etc.), stick to the Python dict literal syntax instead.